# Kafka Sink Connector Elastic Cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to connect kafka to Elastic cloud via url, username and password.
I get a 404 error so I guess that the configuration is not the right one to connect to the Elastic cluster.
How can I connect to Elastic Cloud?

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
type.name=_doc
connection.password=my_pass_elastic
topics=demo-topic-distributed
tasks.max=1
connection.username=my_user_elastic
connection.url=https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx-xxx-x.aws.found.io:port
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.ignore=true
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
schema.ignore=true


org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Could not create index 'demo-topic-distributed': 404 Not Found
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.createIndex(JestElasticsearchClient.java:458)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.createIndices(JestElasticsearchClient.java:425)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.createIndicesForTopics(ElasticsearchWriter.java:374)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.open(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:131)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.openPartitions(WorkerSinkTask.java:617)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.access$1100(WorkerSinkTask.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask$HandleRebalance.onPartitionsAssigned(WorkerSinkTask.java:682)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.invokePartitionsAssigned(ConsumerCoordinator.java:293)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:430)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:449)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:365)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:508)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1261)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1230)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.pollConsumer(WorkerSinkTask.java:454)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:229)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The credentials I use in the **connection.username** and **connection.password** field are the same ones I use to access kibana from the cluster.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the URL and crednetials of your **Elastic** host, *not* Kibana.

From Elastic cloud you should have a `Copy endpoint` button

[image]